# Generate text based on randomized CSS file

Tags: javascript, css

My webpage has a random CSS function that's working fine:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/<?php echo(mt_rand(1,7));?>.css" />
```

But I would like to have text display based on which CSS file is selected.  Each one has a name associated with it, so for the "Copenhagen" CSS sheet I want it to display the text, "This stylesheet is called Copenhagen."

Right now I'm trying to output text based on the background-color of *.skills-title*, which for now is either black, white, or everything else ("Fail").  However it's not outputting anything at all.  I think it's because the stylesheet is randomized so I can't call a specific stylesheet into the code.

```html
var color = $('.skills-title').css('background-color');

if (color == 'rgb(255, 255, 255)') {
  document.write("Copenhagen");
} else if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 0)') {
  document.write("Paris");
} else {
  document.write("Fail");
}
```

After playing around with a lot of different code for a few hours, I feel stuck.

Comment: Why not to do this with PHP, where the information is easily available. Instead of creating and echoing the random filename in `link` tag, store it into a variable, and echo the variable in the `link` as well as where ever you need the value.

Comment: @Teemu that was a wonderful idea that worked for me!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set an `id` or `title` to your Link tag, so you could get it in vanilla js as follow:

```
// supposing you created it like: <link id="mylink" title="mylinktitle" rel="stylesheet" href="/css/<?php echo(mt_rand(1,7));?>.css" />

let element = document.querySelector("link[title=mylinktitle]")

// or 

let element = document.getElementById("mylink");
```

With element object you could check anything and display the name you want.

Alternatively you could try to send the name in title and use an static id, so you get the element based on some id and display the title associated